# about constraints in class diagram

Tags: uml, constraints, class-diagram

Take the following class diagram:
[image]

I want to model the following constraint:
A member must not participate in several thesis defences programmed on the same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a qualifier to express that given a date, there will be zero or one Thesis Defence. That looks like an extra rectangle on the Member end of the association containing the string "defence date : DateTime" and a multiplicity of [0..1] on the other end. Please see [Qualified Association | Applying UML and Patterns: UML Class Diagrams | InformIT](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398623&seqNum=16) for an example.

Comment: @ Jim L. this means that thesis defence has 0..1 member per date defence?. if this is the case, My class diagram becomes not correct!

Comment: I don't see how. Please elaborate.

Comment: You drew it backwards.

Comment: @ Jim L. So, I can put the qualifier near the Member class , and it contains the string "defence date : DateTime. But Member do not have  an attribute "defence date" !!

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. Would you mind removing or fixing the backwards diagram for the next reader?

Answer (score 1):

If you append `{bag}` to the multiplicity it tells the reader that the set is unique.

From Superstructures 2.1.1:

> Various other notations can be placed near the end of the line as follows:
>
> - A multiplicity
> - A property string enclosed in curly braces. The following property strings can be applied to an association end:
>
>   - {subsets `<property-name>`} to show that the end is a subset of the property called `<property-name>`.
>   - {redefines `<end-name>`} to show that the end redefines the one named `<end-name>`.
>   - {union} to show that the end is derived by being the union of its subsets.
>   - {ordered} to show that the end represents an ordered set.
>   - {bag} to show that the end represents a collection that permits the same element to appear more than once. • {sequence} or {seq} to
>       show that the end represents a sequence (an ordered bag).
>   - If the end is navigable, any property strings that apply to an attribute.

To add further constraints like the date to be unique you should attach that constraint to the connector rather than the object.